# telegram bots, how to request input from user?

Tags: command, telegram, telegram-bot

I know how to use telegram commands, and know how to read what command has been executed. What I would like to do is something like this:

```
User: /send_address
Bot: Hello, please type your address..
User: my address...
```

so far, i can read the /send_address command and reply with "hello,...." and obviously I can also read the answer of the user, just like I have read the /send_address command. Question is, how do i know if the answer he sends is in response to my "hello, please type your address.." request, or if he sent it just because? I could have 100 users chatting with the bot, would i have to store a variable for each user remembering that he sent the /send_address cmd?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I known, telegram has no way to save state for user. I use a table in database for saving comands of user.

How it works:

1. User say /command
2. Store /command for User.
3. User say "something" we try to get data from database for this user. If we find out that previos message is command /command than do some action and save nowly added data (if you have multiple steps for some command)